# Recompile only changed files (two-steps)

Tags: c++, makefile, timestamp, preprocessor

I have read several questions here on SO, but still my `Makefile` won't do what I want. Contrary to other questions, I have a *two-steps compilation* here. The steps are these:

- use a preprocessor tool (called `ppx`) that generates `.cpp` and `.h` files,
- then compile them generating `.o` files,
- finally create a dynamic library.

All of this is inside the Xcode environment (custom build target) so you can see all those `$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)` and similar variables.

The `make` command is invoked **where the `ppx` files are**, but I need to place all generated files (`.cpp`, `.h`, `.o`, and `.dylib`) in the right directory (see `$(LIB)`).

Beware: the `ppx` tool **does not preserve timestamps**.

This is my failed attempt:

```
# target and compiler
LIB=$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/$(TARGET_NAME).dylib
PPX=$(HOME)/bin/ppx

# c++ compiler
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14 

# files 
PPX_FILES := $(patsubst %.ppx, %.cpp, $(wildcard *.ppx))
CPP_FILES := $(patsubst %.ppx, %.o, $(wildcard *.ppx))
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/,$(CPP_FILES:%.cpp=%.o))

# link library
all: $(LIB)

$(LIB): $(PPX_FILES) $(CPP_FILES) $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CXX) -dynamiclib -o $(LIB) $(OBJ_FILES)

# preprocess, generating source and header
%.cpp: %.ppx 
    $(PPX) -o $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR) $<

# compile cpp source files
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Ofast -o $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/$@ -c $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/$<
```

The above `Makefile` recompiles always all files. After reading all questions I've found here, the only thing I've succeeded to do is to have a never-recompiling `Makefile`, so that when I changed the `ppx` files it did nothing.

Can you help me spot the errors?

Comment: Your variables `PPX_FILES` and `CPP_FILES` are misleading, as `PPX_FILES` list the C++ source files and `CPP_FILES` lists the object files. You also don't need to fetch the file-names from the disk for each variable, just replace the suffix of the first variable.

Comment: Does your ppx tool regenerate files that have not changed? Do their timestamps change?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, it does. I am trying to use `make` to avoid this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know, but I am not that well versed in `make` to have a clear list of files.

Comment: What is the file name generated by the `ppx` command when you just give it a directory? Is it the same as the input filename but with a different extension?

Comment: Either way, the issue is that `make` doesn’t find a lot of the files because they aren’t in the directory it’s looking in. And I haven’t used `make` recently enough to figure out how to fix it if you really need to generate the files in `$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)`, but I think the usual solution is to generate all the files in the same directory and have an `install` target for copying the needed files to the right location. There’s also a `make` variable that helps, but I don’t remember what it is.

Comment: @DanielH `ppx` does not take as input a directory, just a file to preprocess. I am playing with `touch` but it does not help setting timestamps manually.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, `ppx` doesn't preserve timestamps? Neither does `gcc -c`. That's the point of `make` rules; tools aren't even invoked if the output timestamps are up to date. And if they're outdated, then timestamps *shouldn't* be preserved as a new output file is generated

Comment: I thought differently. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @senseiwa What I meant is that you call `ppx` with `-o $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)`; since that’s a directory, what file name does it generate inside that directory?

Comment: Uh sorry. No, that switch is the output directory, it takes the last parameter as the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Constructing `foo.cpp` and `foo.h` from `foo.ppx`, and putting them in the right directory. (I understood you to mean that "the right directory" is `$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)`, but you were a little cryptic.)

```
# preprocess, generating source and header
$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/%.cpp: %.ppx
    $(PPX) -o $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR) $<
```

or better:

```
# preprocess, generating source and header
$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/%.cpp: %.ppx
    $(PPX) -o $(dir $@) $<
```

**Step 2:** Constructing `foo.o` from `foo.cpp` and `foo.h` (and `bar.h` and `baz.h`, as needed. I advise you to look into automatic dependency handling next.)

```
# compile cpp source files
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Ofast -o $@ -c $<
```

**Step 3:** Constructing a list of needed object files, with a sensible name:

```
# files                                     
PPX_FILES := $(wildcard *.ppx)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.ppx, $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/%.o, $(PPX_FILES))
```

**Step 4:** Building the library:

```
$(LIB): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CXX) -dynamiclib -o $@ $^
```

If it is still malfunctioning due to problems with timestamps and ppx (which I don't have to experiment withal), then let us know in a comment; I'm pretty sure the fix is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great. I only have one question: why does `make` remove the generated `cpp` files? I didn't expect that. It's cool with me since I won't need them after creating the library, but is it possible to remove also the `.h` files? (I've already copied them in another directory)

Comment: @senseiwa: Make considers the `cpp` files [*intermediate files*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules), and removes them when their work is done. The simplest way to remove the header (`.h`) files is to add the command `rm -f $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/*.h` to the `$(LIB)` rule. It is possible to get Make to consider them intermediate files, but it's complicated.